# Knockout data-bind text when the name contains a dot

Tags: knockout.js

I retrieved data from Dailymotion API.

```
  "created_time": 1391086059,
  "message": "20 minutes rime avec fils de.",
  "owner.username": "Mejicano777"
```

How to use `data-bind` for the 'text' property on 'owner.username' ?

I tried:

```
<strong data-bind="text: owner.username"></strong>
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `$data` [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) property and use the array indexer syntax to access your property with a dot in its name:

```
<strong data-bind="text: $data['owner.username']"></strong>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rMR3/).